# Write failure on the node due to excessive load in my Cassandra cluster

Tags: database, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.0

I am getting frequently this exception on Cassandra nodes like below.

**Too many remote connections are pending**

When we checked the stats we didn't find any overload symtoms and no high traffic on that node. However, this is non-impacting exception as we have enough RF.

Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Write failures indicate that the `commitlog` disk cannot keep up with the traffic.

The disk can only provide so much IO and once you've reached its limit, the only solution is to add more nodes so you can increase the capacity of the cluster. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Erick, I checked commit log directory and there is enough space and traffic is not coming too much in the cluster. Any specific limit you are indicating here?

Comment: Can we increase commitlog_total space in Cassandra.yaml if that will help ?

Comment: It's not a space issue. It's how much IO your commitlog disk can sustain. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to check if the cassandra session is correctly closed after usage

Comment: I checked session but it is closing after usage.